# How to index an annonymous object using Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

So, the title pretty much sums it up accurately. What I am doing is importing a series of functions into an index file called "**ops.ts**", and **ops.ts** is exporting these functions using the "`export`" syntax (code snippets below). I am then importing `ops.ts` from another file, and calling dynamically calling these functions. A slight issue is that I am unable to index the object from `ops.ts` using string keys (I'm not so familiar with Typescript, so I'm not exactly sure what's wrong). Specifically, I get the error `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the relevant code:

```
ops.ts

export { default as add } from "./ops/add.ts";
export { default as mult} from "./ops/mult.ts";
```

```
add.ts

export default function add(a: number, b: number): number {
  return a + b;
}
```

```
main.ts
import * as ops from "./ops.ts"
class example {
  //irrelavent code
  constructor() {
     Object.keys(ops).forEach((op: string) => {
        this.operators[op] = ops[op];
     });
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not simply do this.operators = ops?

Comment: Because it seems like my ability as a coder goes out the window when I'm trying to learn something new. Thanks for the simple fix, looks like I was over complicating Typescript a bit.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things in that.

1. Depending on the way you compile your module, you can have additional fields in result JS-object. Typescript will not allow you to index them, but `Object.keys()` and other means of iterating keys will. And you probably don't want to have `"__esModule": true` field in your `operations` array. (check console output in sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-lake-x72y3?file=/src/index.ts )
2. The typings for `Object.keys()` are generalized. It could return array of `keyof typeof ops`, but for simplicity it is just `string`. And you generally cannot index objects of a specific type with arbitrary strings. You have to cast it explicitly, like `operations[key] = ops[key as keyof typeof ops]`.

As for how to deal with that, I would suggest importing your operations as associative array, so you don't actually have to iterate through keys of a module. Like so:

```
//ops.ts
import { default as add } from "./add";
import { default as mult } from "./mult";

export const allOperations = { add, mult }
```

As an opinionated side note, I would suggest avoiding default exports in TypeScript: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/defaultisbad

Comment: Alright, thanks for the suggestion! Typescript seems to have a lot of knacks to it.